# Issue while checking whether user has particular group using ContainerCriteria in LDAP

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

Currently i am developing an application where users are authenticated via LDAP. The criteria for successful login is based on correct username,password and group(TEST-FFSUS-CALBR-USER).

i was able to login successfully with username and password criteria , but not with group criteria.

Following are the code used for this purpose :

```
 @Resource
 LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

public boolean login(String username, String password) {
         try {
                ContainerCriteria searchCriteria = getLdapFilterCriteria(username);
                boolean result = ldapTemplate.authenticate("OU=User,OU=fo-id,DC=feefusde,DC=rootdom,DC=net",
                        searchCriteria.filter().encode(), password);
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
    }

 private ContainerCriteria getLdapFilterCriteria(String usernameOrEmail) {
        ContainerCriteria objectClassCriteria = LdapQueryBuilder.query().base("DC=rootdom,DC=net").where("objectClass")
                .is("user");
        ContainerCriteria mailCriteria = LdapQueryBuilder.query().where("mail").is(usernameOrEmail);
        ContainerCriteria cnCriteria = LdapQueryBuilder.query().where("CN").is(usernameOrEmail);
        ContainerCriteria roleCriteria = LdapQueryBuilder.query().where("memberOf=CN").is("TEST-FFSUS-CALBR-USER");
        ContainerCriteria userByMailOrCnCriteria = mailCriteria.or(cnCriteria);
        ContainerCriteria searchCriteria = objectClassCriteria.and(userByMailOrCnCriteria).and(roleCriteria);
        return searchCriteria;
    }
```

In application-context:

```
 <bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <property name="contextSource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
            <constructor-arg>
                <value>ldap://urlofldap:portno</value>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="userDn" value="${ldap.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${ldap.password}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Is there any way to fix above issue. ?

Answer (score 0):

The `memberOf` attribute should match the group distinguished name. For example `"CN=TEST-FFSUS-CALBR-USER,OU=roles,DC=feefusde,DC=rootdom,DC=net"`:

```
ContainerCriteria roleCriteria = LdapQueryBuilder.query().where("memberOf").is(groupDN);
```

Comment: I already tried " LdapQueryBuilder.query().where("memberOf").is("TEST-FFSUS-CALBR-USER"); "  it didnt worked .

Comment: @JobyWilsonMathews Of course it didn't work ! What you tried is incorrect,  don't you see the difference between `"TEST-FFSUS-CA‌​LBR-USER"` and `"CN=TEST-FFSUS-CALBR-USER,OU=roles,DC=feefusde,DC=rootdom,DC=net"` ? I clearly stated that the `memberOf` attribute should match the group **distinguished name**. `"TEST-FFSUS-CA‌​LBR-USER"` is not a dn. Also, in your question you mentioned the filter `where("memberOf=CN")` and it won't work regardless of the dn parameter.